# Automatic Plotting in *.r file

Tags: r, plot

I do have a *.r file where I order it to coduct a Chi Square of Independence and write it to an html file. It's working fine but I'd like to add a graph.

Doing by hand in R with linecommands works perfectly, but the exact same commands do not work in the *.r file but i want it to do it automatically.

```
mat1 <-matrix(c(12,3,2,12),nrow=2,byrow=T)
attach(mat1)
png('independence.png')
barplot(mat1,beside=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Is there an additional command necessary?

kind regards

Comment: 'brow" is what? (I'm not surprised it doesn't work since it throws an error at my console.)

Comment: thx :) but no, thats not the mistake. R is on my laptop and im writing here from my desktop computer.
There is no error message at all.

Comment: How are you writing to the html file? Are you using `knitr` or doing it manually somehow? Either way, you should try to expand your example to include the lines where you try to write to the file.

Comment: Well, it was _a_ mistake. Furthermore, you should not use `attach()` (ever), and it throws another error on my machine so I think that is why your script fails. I cannot see a purpose to attach here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error in a script with no `try` or `tryCatch`, then entrie script fails. By trying to `attach` a matrix, you throw an error  with the message:

```
Error in attach(mat1) : 
  'attach' only works for lists, data frames and environments
```

So you should pay more attention to the error messages in interactive mode, and if you are planning to use `.r` files for production you should learn to use error handling routines in R. The `attach function is a common source of new user errors, although this error is not particularly common. The more common errors with its use involve regression functions where the authors of the functions are expecting entire objects, usually dataframes, to be passed to a data argument.